# Data Validation arrow hidden from freeze panes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, freeze, data-validation

I've been searching with no luck about my issue of the data validation drop-down arrow being hidden by freeze panes.

I have read multiple forum posts about Excel 97 having this as a bug, but fixed in future versions.

Essentially the cells with data validation on the section of the sheet that are frozen panes, have the drop-down arrow hidden when I start scrolling.

Some things that might be of relevance: there are a few hidden columns scattered throughout (but I don't think that's affecting anything), it is a macro-enabled document.

From what I understand, this shouldn't happen in Excel 2010, but I'm at a loss as to why it's being hidden.

The options for the workbook about "Show All" for objects, is checked. I'd prefer not to use the Split feature either, because I'm finding the same issue with that.

I've also tried repairing the document on open.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Edit: Apologies, assume a typical table setup with headings across say...30 columns and data for 10 - 20 rows as an example. In cell D2 I have hit Freeze Panes so that the top row is frozen and A,B,C columns are frozen. The data validation in column C works until I begin scrolling to the right, and then the arrow disappears. Basically it seems as though column D goes overtop of the drop-down arrow.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Additional detail would be helpful in answering this question. I'm having trouble visualizing what you mean. Where is your data validation located compared to the frozen panes? Is it a horizontal pane where the data validation is at the top of the bottom pane? Or is it at the bottom of the top pane?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the right of column C, col width=2 seems to work well.  Then move the pane to be next to that new column. It's hokey, but I can't find any other solution.