# Why does the dropdown button in Excel data validation disappear?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, data-validation, list

I am creating a dashboard in Excel in which I want to restrict the input to a specific list. I used data validation to do so which works perfectly fine. However, normally the little drop-down button is visible when I select a cell (it is in any other workbook), but in my dashboard it keeps disappearing. Here is a small [gif](http://makeagif.com/i/WpXbWl) of the problem.

**Why won't the button stay visible?**

Extra info: In the dashboard, I make use of VBA code and OpenSolver. Could they play a part in any of this?

Comment: When you make the list in Data Validation, there is an option to show the little drop down arrow. Is it checked?

Comment: Yes it is indeed

Comment: Have you tried opening the affected file on other computer? Or try making a simple drop down list in a new blank file, and see if it behaves the same. If both gives the proper behavior, then yes, it might have to be something with your VBA.

Comment: In other files it does work. Another computer had the same issue indeed. Spitting through the VBA code will be one heck of a job. Would not know where to start. Thanks for the help anyways :)

Comment: I asked this question a few years back, which I think might be the same or a similar situation?

https://superuser.com/questions/746008/data-validation-arrow-hidden-from-freeze-panes

Do you have freeze panes enabled?  edit: I found that with data validation and freeze panes, there's really no fix for it. At least, I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @Ferenth It sounds similar, but i don't have freeze panes. Also scrolling seems to play no part in it. The buttons are hidden all the time (after brief flashes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in some versions of excel.

If you used the camera tool, then if the input cells of the camera tool object (the linked cells) are on a different worksheet as the data validation dropdown enabled cells, the dropdown arrows go missing.

They aren't actually gone, however:

- You can still access the dropdown if you select the dropdown enabled cell and move the cursor to the right where the arrow would normally appear and click. It works, but it's annoying and makes it difficult for other users if the worksheet is intended for users other than yourself.
- You can also click on the dropdown enabled cell and hit Alt-Downarrow, and the list will appear. Again this may not be ideal or obvious for other users.

Potential Fixes:

- You could remove the camera tool object and everything should work fine.
- If the input cells of the camera tool object (the linked cells) are on the same worksheet as the data validation dropdown enabled cells, the problem doesn't exist. Thus, you could move the linked cells that the camera tool is referencing to the same sheet with the dropwdown enabled cells.
- **BEST SOLUTION THAT REQUIRES NO MAJOR CHANGES**: A strange solution that seems to work (for an unknown reason) is if you create a combo box (form control) and set the cell link and input range to =$1:$1048576 (this references all cells) on one of the sheets affected by the flashing arrows. This should stop the arrows from flashing/disappearing on the page with the combo box as well as all arrows in the whole workbook. You can put it in some obscure location on the sheet so it isn't visible to the user.

Comment: I created the combo box as suggested, on a hidden sheet. It works! What a bizarre fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same disappearing drop-down button behaviour shown in your gif. It might be there are other things that cause this behaviour as well but in my case it was caused by using the camera tool.

Deleting the camera image restored the normal drop-down button visibility. Creating a camera image anywhere in the workbook caused all drop-down buttons to act shy again.

Comment: Welcome to  Superuser, i do believe that your answer needs proper illustration to solve the issue. Since you are unable to address the OP so please edit the post to compose a useful answer. you may refer this link also,, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Hi, you might be right. I indeed also used the camera tool. I could not have guessed that would be the problem. If you could add a little illustration as suggested by Rajesh I am happy to accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I went to Options then *"Advanced"*, then scrolled down to *"Display options for this workbook:"* Then in the *"For all objects, show:"* I clicked *"All"*. Worked for me. I have no idea how this setting changed in the 1st place though.